# C# Read Excel with Lists

Tags: c#, excel

I have an Excel file with two sheets. The first sheet contains data and the second sheet contains a bunch of **lists** that I use to validate cells on the first sheet.

When I read the excel file using C# via OLEDB, instead of focusing on the first sheet, it focuses on one of the lists.

This is what my sheet looks like:

[image]

On the second sheet:

[image]

What I run the upload process, it points to the "16-20" column on the second sheet.

Any idea why?

This is my code:

```
        using (var connection = new OleDbConnection(string.Format(ExcelConnectionString, excelFile)))
        {
            connection.Open();
            var schema = connection.GetOleDbSchemaTable(OleDbSchemaGuid.Tables, null);
            using (var command = new OleDbCommand(string.Format("SELECT * FROM [{0}]", schema.Rows[0]["TABLE_NAME"]), connection))
            {
                using (var dataAdapter = new OleDbDataAdapter(command))
                {
                    dataAdapter.Fill(dataTable);
                }
            }
        }
```

The first sheet has some fields which require a drop-down, like Job Role. So, I have added all the lists on the second sheet which are: List of Regions, List of Job Roles, List of Age Ranges and List of Qualifications.

For some reason, the upload process points to the Age Ranges, i.e. 16-20, 21-25 etc.

On the top left hand corder of Excel, there is a dropdown which allows you to navigate to all of the lists, coincidently, the first list is the Age Ranges. It seems as if it uses this to index the schema/list/tables.

[image]

Comment: I would suggest to use ExcellDataReader http://exceldatareader.codeplex.com/ instead of OleDB